# USB video playback on my TV

Tags: usb, cec-client

I have a 4k video that I wanted to play, and while I realise RPi can't play 4k, I know that my TV does. So i plugged in USB drive into TV, and now I'm trying to figure out a way for my raspberry to tell TV to play video from USB input. I tried to use CEC for that but I couldn't find any useful commands, and simulating sequence of remote control button presses seems just too unpractical.

It's important that raspberry pi is capable to launch that command, since I need to be able to synchronise playback with GPIO output.

My TV is Sony Bravia smart TV, which has system based on Android. So is there possibly any way to tell the TV to launch it's media player and straight into the video I'm interested in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Every Raspberry Pi can have 4k resolution. Just add

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 3840 2160 24
max_framebuffer_width=3840
max_framebuffer_height=2160
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=400000000
```

to *config.txt*.
If you need more than 24fps, change the 24 to 30.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own remote program like OpenBravia and send it android\root commands or make a remote control like video-tv-sideview but that would just be like your remote control or phone app. Or if your TV can run kodi you can send it commands too.

Comment: I think Kodi could work, I'm just not sure how to send commands from raspberry to Kodi ran on TV. Is there a way to send something through USB, or would it have to be CEC again?

Comment: Depending on what you are using Kodi on you can use terminal commands threw ssh. Also you Kodi can access the network and play from another device. And also depending on your device you can use your phone or remote to control kodi. none of these use CEC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Raspberry Pi, but it seems that it would be easier to play a movie via USB by plugging the USB into the RPi, then plugging the HDMI into your TV.